# How can deploy Angular universal on windows server

Tags: angular, web-config, angular-universal

i have problem  to deploy (publish) my website as angular universal and i tried everything almost.

When i run `npm run dev:ssr` in the localhost it works well and i can see the pages source even dynamic's.

in my `dist` folder i have:

- dist

  - broswer (include `index.html` and etc ..)
  - server (include `main.js`)

i read about `iisnod` to set it in the `web.config` but i can't get the result as server side page, **my question is** how can i publish the angular universal on my website (IIS) ?

What should i do for that?

Comment: perhaps you are better of using asp.net on your iis and then using the [`aspnetcore-engine`](https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/aspnetcore-engine/README.md) from angular universal

Comment: Show your issue config

Answer (score 0):

Deploing the Angular SSR in to IIS is a bad practical.
Use Node.js and PM2 https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Steps to deploy on Windows Server

1. Install Node.js
2. Install PM2

   - type command 'npm i pm2@latest -g'
3. Build the Angular app
4. Deploy `/dist/**` folter to the server.
5. Follow to
6. Start PM2

   - type command 'pm2 start <path_to_server_script/main.js> --name <app_name>'
7. Enjoy

The PM2 runs Node.js server. If you want redeploy your application, when after deploy restart PM2. Command - 'pm2 respart <app_name>'